# Displaying number of search results in Wicket form

Tags: java, forms, search, wicket

In my current Apache Wicket project I have a search form for querying the database and displaying the query results in a `ListView`. The search input box is on the same page as the `ListView` with the results, and that `ListView` is filled with query results from a DAO, during invocation of the onSubmit() method of the form.

Everything works fine, but I need to display the number of search results. I tried to create a Label that is filled with the value of the size() method of the list got by the `getList()` method of the `ListView` instance, but no luck.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you please show some of the code you're using?

Comment: Can you provide some code? E.g. die place where you construct the label?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you have built this form, you might only need to do `label.setModelObject(listResults.size())`. It's difficult to tell without seeing how are you doing it.

By what you're telling in your question, probably you're creating your Label like this `new Label(labelId, listView.getList().size()`. This won't work, you're setting the Label's Model at construction time with a constant value, that's the size of the list at construction time. You need to get that value inside a `Model`'s `getObject()` to make the value "dynamic". Like, for instance,

```
AbstractReadOnlyModel sizeModel = new AbstractReadOnlyModel(){
    public getObject(){
        return listView.getList().getSize();
    }
}
new Label(labelId, sizeModel);
```

With this, every time the page renders, `sizeModel().getObejct()` will be called to retrieve the value for the `Label`. In that other way, the `Label` has got a `Model` with a constant value.

You could even do `label.setModelObject(list.size())` in the `onSubmit()` method.

From my ignorance on how you have built this form, I'll show you how would I do this. The `List` of results would be retrieved with a `LoadableDetachableModel`. That would be the `Model` of the `ListView`. Then, the `Label` can have for instance an `AbstractReadOnlyModel` that uses the `ListView`s modelObject to get its size.

```
public class MyForm extends Form {


    private LoadableDetachableModel resultsModel;
    private IModel searchModel;
    public MyForm(){
        searchModel = new Model();
        TextField searchTextField = new TextField("search", searchModel);
        resultsModel = new LoadableDetachableModel(){
             protected Object load(){
                 return myService.get(searchModel.getModelObject());
             }
        }
        ListView lv = new ListView("list", resultsModel){
            // ...
        }
        Label resultsCount = new Label("count", new AbstractReadOnlyModel(){
              public Object getObject(){
                   return ((List) resultsModel.getObject()).size();
              }
        })
        SubmitButton button = new SubmitButton(){
             public void onSubmit(){
                 //... No actions needed, really
             }
        }
        // add's...
    }
}
```

Using a [`LoadableDetachableModel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/LoadableDetachableModel.html) for the `ListView` has the advantage of automatically detaching the `Model`, and therefore avoiding the whole `List` of results to get serialized into the `Session`.